# Achartengine how to move the symbol (legend) as show in the picture

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I use

```
String[] titles = new String[]{"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSleep Duration","\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nExercise"};
```

to move Sleep Duration down but the symbol for sleep duration didn't move down.
To to move it down?
As shown in the picture below.

[image: AchartEngine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that just decrease the font size of Sleep Duration and Exercise then 
give a long blank space after Sleep Duration to let Exercise move below Sleep duration
String[] titles = new String[]{"Sleep Duration                                    ","\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nExercise"};